# SQL update with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to set the value of all items in a column of one **table(A)**, related to a condition given in another **table(C)**. To solve this job, I mentioned to use this query:

```
Update Table1 AS A
SET A.Value = '1'
FROM Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.item = B.item
INNER JOIN Table3 AS C
ON B.item = C.item
WHERE C.Value = '2'
```

Sadly, this isn't working so far, so, where is my mistake?

Here is the original code:

```
Update wp_postmeta 
SET A.meta_value = '0.25'
FROM wp_postmeta AS A
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS B
ON B.meta_id = A.meta_id 
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_item  AS C
ON C.order_item_id = B.order_item_id 
WHERE C.Value = '%250g%'
```

Comment: Which DB are you using (Oracle, Postgres etc)? Please add it to your tags

Comment: when you say it isn't working, do you get an error, or does it run and not make any updates?

Comment: I get this error message: 1064 - Error in SQL syntax  near 'FROM wp_postmeta AS A
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS B
ON B' at line 3

Comment: @NiclasSchwarz ok its probably the A. in your SET, see my answer below

Comment: @istovatis from the error message looks like MySql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be the 'as A' on the first line thats the problem. try

```
Update Table1 
SET Value = '1'
FROM Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN Table2 AS B
ON A.item = B.item
INNER JOIN Table3 AS C
ON B.item = C.item
WHERE C.Value = '2'
```

edit: in your specific code, I think A. after SET is the problem. Try:

```
Update wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = '0.25'
FROM wp_postmeta AS A
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS B
ON B.meta_id = A.meta_id 
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_item  AS C
ON C.order_item_id = B.order_item_id 
WHERE C.Value = '%250g%'
```

Explanation: in the context of the 'update...set' part of the statement, the abbreviation 'A' makes no sense to the sql server.

edit: or you can do it as suggested by i486 in comments below.

Comment: Or `Update A SET a.value='1' from Table 1 AS A...`.

Comment: @i486 yeah thats quite nice actually

Comment: execpt for the typo in order_itemS this one solved my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query in a style similar to a select statement. This is IMHO more readable and you run an explain on it quickly by just exchanging 2 words.

Here is how the Update would look like:

```
UPDATE Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
  ON A.item = B.item
INNER JOIN Table3 C
  ON B.item = C.item
SET A.Value = '1'
WHERE C.Value = '2';
```

This style also enables you to updated columns in other tables than A, if you need to in the same statement.

If you want to run a explain plan, to see if the joins work correctly you would simply do this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B
  ON A.item = B.item
INNER JOIN Table3 C
  ON B.item = C.item
-- SET A.Value = '1'
WHERE C.Value = '2';
```